# Drupal 7 Views Isotope Error

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have an ecommerce site using the module views isotope to display the product grid. After a recent upgrade, It looks like my view is broken and I'm getting this warning:

> "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
>   ...(my theme directory)".

The warning can be viewed here: http://biltriteinc.com/?q=supports

What is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Error is as stated..

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in goodnex_item_list() (line 212 of /home/biltrite/public_html/sites/all/themes/goodnex/template.php)
```

Whatever is calling `in_array` in `goodnex_item_list` is not passing an array as the second argument and instead is passing a string. You'll have to backtrack from there to figure out what and why.

See: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I appreciate the insight. I'll have to do a little bit of digging since I'm using a child theme, in the era seems to be in the parent.

Comment: You can "bring in" and override that in the child theme by copying and pasting the function into template.php of your theme and naming it themename_item_list. That might help with debugging efforts.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that.